# Are there Type III codes with small but nonzero "index"?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, lattices, supersymmetry

Recall that a *Type III code* of rank $r$ is a linear subspace $C \subset \mathbb F_3^r$ which is self-dual for the standard inner product. (These occur only when $r$ is divisible by $4$.) Elements of $C$ are called *code words*. The *Hamming weight* of a code word is its number of non-zero entries. I will call a code word *maximal* if its Hamming weight is $r$. (Maximal codewords clearly only occur when $r$ is divisible by $12$.)

The set of maximal codewords can be partitioned into two subsets as follows: two maximal words $w_1,w_2$ are in the same subset if $w_1-w_2$ has even Hamming weight, and are in opposite subsets if $w_1-w_2$ has odd Hamming weight. Call these subsets $M_+$ and $M_-$.

I suggest the following definition:

**Definition:** The *index* of $C$ is $|M_+| - |M_-|$. Of course, this is only defined up to sign. I could take its absolute value if I cared. The name is because this is related to the "supersymmetric index" of a certain supersymmetric field theory.

The discussion in the comments of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295763/) implies the following when $r$ is divisible by $24$:

**Proposition:** The index of any Type III code of rank $r=24k$ is divisible by $24$.

**Conjecture:** This is true also when $r \equiv 12 \mod 24$. (It is trivially true for $r \equiv \pm 4 \mod 12$, as then $M_\pm$ are empty.)

Moreover, I suspect that both $|M_+|$ and $|M_-|$ are necessarily divisible by $24$.

**Example:** The Ternary Golay code, with rank $12$ has index $24$. It is the unique rank-$12$ code with non-zero index.

**Example:** The complete classification of Type III codes of rank $24$ is [known](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.0637). Assuming I read it correctly, there are precisely five codes of rank $24$ and index $24$.

> **Question:** In higher rank, do there exist Type III codes with index exactly $24$? For example, what about rank $36$?

At best, there would be some general algorithm that produces a code with index $24$ for each rank $r = 12k$.

By the way, I know how to prove:

**Proposition:** If the code $C$ contains words of Hamming weight $3$, then its index vanishes.

So if you are looking for such a code, you know not to look at such codes.

It's pretty easy to show:

**Lemma:** The index multiplies when you take the direct sum of codes.

Since $24^2$ is pretty big, you probably will want to work with indecomposable codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Index $24$ isn't hard for length $36$.
For example, the Type III code with generator matrix

```
+ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 + - + 0 - - + 0 + + - + + - 0 -
0 + 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 - 0 - + - - 0 0 - 0 0 0 0 - + - - -
0 0 + 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 - + 0 + - - - + + - + 0 - 0 - +
0 0 0 + 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 + 0 + - + 0 0 + 0 + 0 - - + -
0 0 0 0 + 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 - + 0 0 - 0 - + 0 + 0 - - 0 + 0 + -
0 0 0 0 0 + 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + - 0 - - 0 + + 0 + 0 + 0 - 0 - + 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 - + 0 0 - + 0 - - 0 0 - + - 0 0 - +
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + + - - - - - + 0 + - - - 0 + - 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + + - - + + 0 + - 0 + 0 0 + + + + -
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 - + + + 0 0 - + + - + - - 0 + 0 - -
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + + 0 0 0 - + + + + + 0 - 0 - 0 0 +
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 0 0 - - + 0 0 - 0 + - - + 0 - +
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 - 0 0 - + - - 0 - + + - 0 0 +
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 0 0 0 + 0 - + - - - - 0 0 - 0 - - - - - -
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 0 0 - 0 - - - 0 + + 0 + - 0 - 0 - + 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 0 + - - + 0 0 - 0 - + - + - - - + + 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 - 0 + - 0 - 0 + 0 - - 0 + 0 0 - - -
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 + 0 + + + + - + 0 - - 0 + 0 + - - - +
```

has index $24$.  (The total number of maximal codewords is $520$; of
$70$ "random" Type III codes I tried, $26$ had index $24$ -- which indeed 
was the most common index -- and all had index divisible by $24$, 
while the number of maximal codewords was always a multiple of $8$ 
but not necessarily $24$.)

Comment: Awesome. By the way, how does one find "random" Type iii codes?

Comment: Thanks!  One way to choose a code uniformly at random is to
randomly choose a nonzero word of weight $0 \bmod 3$, then randomly
choose another in its orthogonal complement, etc.  At each step
at least $1/3$ of words in the subspace satisfy the mod-3 condition,
so if at first you don't succeed, try, try again.  Meanwhile I
generated a few hundred more examples of length $36$, and it's still true that
plenty of them have index $24$ (and none violates the mod-$24$ conjecture).  The same seems to happen for length $48$, though here the calculation for
each code is much slower.

Comment: You are either more patient than I am or you have a faster way to find the list of all maximal codewords than I do. I can generate self dual codes of length 36, but I can't seem to calculate their indexes in a reasonable amount of time, and certainly not fast enough to repeat your trial-and-error search.

Comment: (I want to repeat your calculations because I'm looking for codes with certain symmetries...)

Comment: Once the code is in the form $(I_{r/2} | A)$,
all you need is to list the vectors $x$ such that both $x$ and $Ax$
have maximal weight.  All I did was try all $2^{r/2}$ possible $x$.
Actually only half of them, since we can assume the first coordinate is $+1$.
For $r=36$, that's $131072$ candidates, which takes a few seconds in **gp**
(and probably a fraction of a second in C).  So, little patience is required.
I needed to be a bit more patient for $r=48$ when the time per code
was measured in minutes.  I can e-mail you my **gp** code if it would be of use.

Comment: (That is, assume the first coordinate is $+1$, and double the count.
I wouldn't be surprised if there are more efficient ways to do this,
but that's a discussion for e-mail or possibly a different question.)

Comment: Ok, so the issue is I was trying 3^(r/2) many, and perhaps not being smart about how to try them...